# How do I specify a custom registration app instead of an installed one in Django?

Tags: django, registration

So I created my site that uses django-registration-0.8, but the server hosting it is using 0.7 installed server wide. I don't have access as to how the modules are being looked up, so I tried downloading the 0.8 source and placed the registration/ folder and registered it in settings.py (INSTALLED_APPS) as registration.

Now the custom registration app (0.8) is being seen by django. However, when trying to access the register page I get this error:

```
ImportError at /accounts/register/
No module named backends.default.urls
```

Which is called in urls.py as:

```
(r'^accounts/', include('registration.backends.default.urls')),
```

If I change it to

```
(r'^accounts/', include('registration.urls')),
```

the error is gone, but that means it's using the installed (0.7) version. One of the problems with that version is the activation page being different.

Checking the registration app folder I can see the module exists, in registration/backends/default/urls. So my conclusion is that the registration installed server-wide (0.7) is the one being looked into first before the one I manually extracted from source (0.8).

So my question is how do I make Django look up the 0.8 version I installed as an app, instead of the one installed server-wide? I don't have access to shell (using djangofoo hosting), only manage.py and ftp.

Answer (score 0):

Can you confirm the version being found?  Without direct shell access, you might be able to create a management command to print out the registration.get_version() method.

You could try adding the directory the custom registration app is in to the front of the pythonpath using sys.path.insert(0,[path]).

You could also try renaming the custom registration app (registration2?) to make sure you're seeing it on the pythonpath and importing the right one.

Comment: I did manage to try your third option before, just to see if the custom app is checked, and it is; that's until it encounters a reference to 'registration' in the code, in which case it checks again on the system-wide version, throwing exceptions along the way. BTW my hosting provider solved it for me, by editing my WSGI file to check for the apps installed on my site first before checking on system-wide installed packages. I googled around and the wsgi file seems to be connected to apache so I got no access but he assured me I don't have to worry about future discrepancies.